# Calling CFDictionaryContainsValue() in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, core-foundation

I have a Core Foundation dictionary that I would like to find a specific value in. Naturally I would use CFDictionaryContainsValue() provided by Core Foundation. The first argument is the Core Foundation dictionary to search and the second argument is of type `UnsafePointer<Void>`. I'm looking for a string in the dictionary so I tried something like this:

```
var deviceToFind = "disk1"
var result: kern_return_t = KERN_FAILURE
let classesToMatch = IOServiceMatching(kIOMediaClass)
let classesToMatchDict = (classesToMatch as NSDictionary) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
let matchedDevices = (classesToMatchDict as NSDictionary) as CFDictionaryRef

result = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, classesToMatchCFDictRef, &storageIterator);

if CFDictionaryContainsValue(matchedDevices, &deviceToFind) == true
{
    print("Found disk1")
}
```

But that just crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) at the call to `CFDictionaryContainsValue()`. According to [Apple's documentation for interacting with UnsafePointers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) I'm structuring the call correctly but there's obviously a problem but I'm unsure of how to get it to work.

Comment: "Naturally I would use CFDictionaryContainsValue() provided by Core Foundation" Not naturally at all. A CFDictionary is bridged to NSDictionary, and NSDictionary is bridged to Swift Dictionary. Why not use Dictionary methods?

Comment: Also, never say `if x == true`. Saying `if x` _is_ a true-test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the BSD name from IOReg you cannot retrieve the value from `matchedDevices` directly. You have to iterate through the `storageIterator` and get the BSD name property respectively.

```
var deviceToFind = "disk1"
var storageIterator = io_iterator_t()
var object : io_object_t
var result: kern_return_t = KERN_FAILURE
let classesToMatchDict = IOServiceMatching("IOMedia")

result = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, classesToMatchDict, &storageIterator)

if KERN_SUCCESS == result && storageIterator != 0 {
  repeat {
    object = IOIteratorNext(storageIterator)
    if let data = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(object, kIOBSDNameKey, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0), disk = data.takeRetainedValue() as? String {
      if deviceToFind == disk {
        print("Found \(deviceToFind)")
        break
      }
    }
  } while object != 0
  IOObjectRelease(storageIterator)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be less friction to coerce the CFDictionary to a Swift dictionary and then use Swift primitives.

If you need to stay in CF-land, the following should work:

```
let value = "VALUE" as NSString
let dict = ["KEY": "VALUE"] as CFDictionary

if CFDictionaryContainsValue(dict, unsafeAddressOf(value)) {
    print("contains value")
} else {
    print("does not contain value")
}
```